# Tornado socket connection not closing

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tornado

I have a `Tornado` `SockJs` socket connection. When a connection is closed `on_close` method is called. Whereby I remove the user from the connected clients list. However 'PING' 'PONG' keeps on happening since this connection doesn't looks like closed in real.

```
class EchoWebSocket(sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection):

    def on_open(self,info):
            self.send(str('add')) 

    def on_message(self, message):

        message = simplejson.loads(message)
        TASK = message['TASK']

        if TASK == "PING":
            self.send('PONG')

        elif TASK == 'ADD_CLIENT':
            addUserAfterSocketConnection(self, message, "SOCKJS")

    def on_close(self):
        removeUserAfterSocketConnectionClose(self)
```

If I put the self.close() in on_close() it runs in a recursive loop. I can see there is a `close` and `on_close` method in API, how are they different and what's their intended use?

```
def on_close(self):
    removeUserAfterSocketConnectionClose(self)
    self.close()
```

How can I effectively close this connection so that no 'PING' is sent.

Comment: As I remember, the main task of SockJS is to keep WS connection at all time. Have you checked, that continuing PING-PONGs are not result of SockJS's WS reopening after closing? Plus, continuing PING-PONGs can be result of a network lag, to exclude this you could check by adding a timestamp to a PONG.

Comment: There's a time stamp being sent, I cleared some code for simplicity. Like if I open a new tab, the previous socket connection persists since no close signal is sent. However new connection overwrites the Listeners socket list. Hence updates are sent only to new one though the PING/PONG of old one continue. If I look for--> if socket exists in Listeners list then send PONG, then the connections keeps on swtiching between both the windows. Still looking for an ideal solution how to implement this and handle network drops and other scenarios.

Comment: Another thing to check, I've faced a thing when I was developing with SockJS and Tornado (but it was long polling HTTP, not ws, but overall approach MAY be the same): SockJS attaches to a request a certain ID, that is the same for many requests to keep a session between requests. I'd advise you to check whether or not new WS accidentally attaches to existing SockJS-session hence receiving unwanted PONGs.